# Filter dropdown by another dropdown from a JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, drop-down-menu, filter, dropdown

I'm working on a form that builds 2 dropdown from a single json, I have the manager and the available time for that manager in the JSON.

JSON example:

```
[
   {
      "Error":0,
      "Fecha":"21/09/2017",
      "Gestores":[
         {
            "codGestor":"2",
            "Gestor":"Harold",
            "horarios":[
               {
                  "horaM":"0700",
                  "hora":"07:00AM"
               },
               {
                  "horaM":"0800",
                  "hora":"08:00AM"
               },
               {
                  "horaM":"0900",
                  "hora":"09:00AM"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "codGestor":"3",
            "Gestor":"Ramon",
            "horarios":[
               {
                  "horaM":"0700",
                  "hora":"07:00AM"
               },
               {
                  "horaM":"0800",
                  "hora":"08:00AM"
               },
               {
                  "horaM":"0900",
                  "hora":"09:00AM"
               },
               {
                  "horaM":"1000",
                  "hora":"10:00AM"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

HTML form:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['jsonVelneo'])){
$json = $_SESSION['jsonVelneo']; 
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="SGLabz">

    <title>CitasWeb</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../css/portfolio-item.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/form-basic.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script src="../js/form.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CitasWeb</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Portfolio Item Row -->
        <form class="form-basic" id="form-basic" action="/" method="post">

            <div class="form-title-row">
                <h1>Seleccionar</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Gestor</span>
                    <?php

                    echo '<select name="Gestor">';
                    $jsonData = file_get_contents('https://api.myjson.com/bins/f7d29'); 
                    $jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData);

                    foreach($jsonDataObject->Gestores as $option){
                        echo '<option value=' . $option->codGestor . '>' . $option->Gestor . '</option>';   
                    }

                    echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Horarios</span>
                    <?php

                    echo '<select name="horarios">';
                    $jsonData = file_get_contents('https://api.myjson.com/bins/f7d29'); 
                    $jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData);

                    foreach($jsonDataObject->Gestores->codGestor['Gestor'] as $option){
                        echo '<option value=' . $option->horaM . '>' . $option->Hora . '</option>';                    }

                    echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <button id="consularHorario" >Consultar Horarios</button>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Citas Web 2017</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/pikaday.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/moment.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see the Gestor value on the dropdown but I want to filter the second dropdown to show me when I choose for example codGestor 2, to make the second dropdown with horarios available.

In the HTML code, I'm using the myjson.com API to serve the JSON but in real time I will have that JSON in a PHP variable. I've read in a couple of forums that recommend to do it with JavaScript but i want to do it with jquery because its better. Any recommendations?

Comment: yes, you have to do it with js. search for dynamic dropdown.

Comment: write the jsonData to a js var, then react onSelect of the first select to fill the options of the second select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/f7d29', function(data) {
  var s = document.getElementsByName('s1')[0];
  var s2 = document.getElementsByName('s2')[0];
  for (i = 0; i < data.Gestores.length; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement('option');
    a.value = data.Gestores[i].codGestor;
    a.innerHTML = data.Gestores[i].Gestor;
    s.appendChild(a);
  }
  s.onchange = function() {
    while (s2.firstChild) s2.removeChild(s2.firstChild);
    var d = data.Gestores[this.selectedIndex].horarios;
    for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
      var a = document.createElement('option');
      a.value = d[i].horaM;
      a.innerHTML = d[i].hora;
      s2.appendChild(a);
    }
  };
  s.onchange();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="s1"></select><br>
<select name="s2"></select>
```

Comment: Ben, sorry to bother again but how can i change the jquery to use a variable that already contains the json? cause that URL i use it just to try the page, i use a post to an api before this page and the post returns me a json, and that json is exactly the same to the myjson api.

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery for that. In my mind `a={'a':1}` would work. But I don't recommend you to do that, cause all other things(HTML) are static. Seperating static and dynamic contents will help browser take fully advantage of caching, which would be good to both the server and the client.

Comment: So just write another php simply retuning the json code and use `getJSON('url-to-that-php')`! @E.Galdamez